# Facebook location geocode

Tags: facebook

When requesting users to register with Facebook connect I can access their hometown (which is a location id as well as the name).  Is anyone aware if it is possible to get the geo-coded location for this (e.g. retrieve the latitude/longitude as well as the name?) I cannot see it as part of the documentation.

I could geocode it using the hometown with the google geo coding service, but was wondering if another option?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. The information you can retrieve about a user is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/). As you can see the only location based info is hometown (like you said). If you want latitude/longitude you will have to calculate it yourself from the hometown.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the id out of the location record that is returned on the user:

```
    "location": {
      "id": "106224666074625", 
      "name": "Austin, Texas"
    },
```

and make a graph call:

```
     GET https://graph.facebook.com/106224666074625?fields=location
```

which returns:

```
    {
      "location": {
        "street": "", 
        "zip": "", 
        "latitude": 30.2672, 
        "longitude": -97.7639
      }, 
      "id": "106224666074625"
    }
```